# Ruby on rails -- Jquery not submiting put request before another post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, methods

I basically want to click a button and then submit a form when the user clicks another button. The form gets submitted but the button doesn't get clicked.

Method in the controller (put):

```
def set_everything
    user.update_column(:everything_set, true)
end
```

And then I have a form:

```
<%= form_tag("http://someotherwebsite.com/post_method", method: :post, id:"form")%>
     <%= some_field %>
     <button type="button" id="form-button">Done</button>
<% end %>
```

And then on the same view I also have another link_to:

```
<%= link_to set_everything_path, method: :put, id:"set-everything-button", style:"display:none" %>
```

My Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#form-button').click(function(){
     $('#set-everything-button').trigger('click');
     setTimeout(function(){ $('form').submit();}, 2000);
   });
});
```

Now I have also tried using a button_to instead of link_to but it still doesn't get clicked and when I try it manually it works just fine.

Comment: Why just don't add `user.update_column(:everything_set, true)` to the controller action where the form goes?

Comment: Try this `user.update_column(everything_set: true)`. Also, keep in mind, when you use `update_column`, all regular update procedures are bypassed. This means validations are skipped, callbacks are skipped and timestamps are not updated.

Comment: Why not just send the PUT request directly in your `#form-button` click handler via `$.ajax`? You could store the target url in a data attribute on the button.

Comment: This code seems potentially broken in a number of ways. To begin with, though, are you using `turbolinks`?

Comment: I don't understand the use case. Why the 2000ms timeout? The form button is triggering the form submit (since you are not canceling it), then the "click" on the link will trigger another request and then after 2s you want to trigger another request? sound like you can just send the form and do whatever set_everything do on the same request, can you explain a little better what you are trying to do? sounds like you are trying to solve the problem the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Put the target url in a data attribute on the button:

```rb
<button type="button" id="form-button" data-trigger-url="<%= set_everything_path %>">Done</button>
```

Send the PUT request directly in your click handler:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#form-button').click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var form = $(this).closest('form');
     var url = $(this).data('trigger-url');
     $.ajax({
       url: url,
       method: 'PUT',
       dataType: 'html',
       success: function(){
         form.submit()
       }
     })
   });
});
```

Don't forget to send back 200 (OK) response from the controller action so that the javascript runs the `success` handler (and thus submits the form):

```rb
def set_everything
  user.update_columns(everything_set: true)
  head :ok, content_type: "text/html"
end
```